# Combine position estimates from Lidar SLAM and PTAM

Tags: slam, navigation, pose, ptam, camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I have an AR drone with a Lidar attached. I have hector_slam running giving out a position estimate for the drone which is working fine. I also have a PTAM node running which is also spitting out a position estimate.

What is the best way to combine these position estimates to give a best guess for the location of the drone?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/231573/combine-position-estimates-from-lidar-slam-and-ptam/) by [andythepandy93](https://answers.ros.org/users/26285/andythepandy93/) on ROS Answers with karma: 55 on 2016-04-10

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [al-dev](https://answers.ros.org/users/18863/al-dev/) on 2016-04-10**:
Are you using these 2 SLAM algorithms to estimate motion increments (local pose estimation) or to estimate a "fused map"+pose within the fused map (map+global pose estimation) ?

**Comment by [andythepandy93](https://answers.ros.org/users/26285/andythepandy93/) on 2016-04-10**:
hector_slam is building up a map as it goes along and giving out  that map and a pose estimate. The PTAM slam is working out increments I think as it gets its key points when it starts up and then goes from there, (it also uses control inputs for the drone for the pose estimate)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It seems that you are running 2 SLAM algorithms in parallel which is a bit confusing, but you could still try one of the following :

1. The output of SLAM is {map+global pose estimate} so you actually have 2 different maps with 2 different global pose estimates. There is no trivial way to fuse all these directly AFAIK. I guess if you are not interested in fusing the maps, you could take one of them as a reference and then just fuse the global pose estimates through an EKF/UKF via the `robot_localization` package.
2. If one of these 2 SLAM algorithms was using odometry as an input and you already had a source of odometry (e.g wheel odometry, visual odometry...)  you could try to use the other SLAM algorithm to provide an alternative odometry estimate, and then fuse it through an EKF/UKF with your existing odometry. Then give the "improved" (?) odometry estimate to your second SLAM algorithm.

For instance, `hector_slam` can provide such an odometry estimate via the undocumented `pub_odometry` parameter, see [this question](http://answers.ros.org/question/104966/using-hector-mapping-for-odometry-with-amcl-for-localization-in-a-pre-given-map/)

The problem here is that none of the two SLAM algorithms you mentioned - I am less familiar with PTAM though - use any source of odometry...
You could try to modify `hector_slam` to use odometry but that requires some work, see [this question](http://answers.ros.org/question/229836/hector-slam-with-odometry-switch/). As for PTAM, I don't know.

---

Originally posted by [al-dev](https://answers.ros.org/users/18863/al-dev/) with karma: 883 on 2016-04-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [andythepandy93](https://answers.ros.org/users/26285/andythepandy93/) on 2016-04-11**:
Okay great there's lots to think about in there, thanks. I had heard of the pub_odometry parameter but not looked into it so will give that a look. Also just looked at the robot_localization package and it looks good. Cheers!